# Arkham horror expansion compatability diagram

Tags: arkham-horror

I once came across a nifty little diagram that had all the Arkham Horror expansions on it with lines drawn between them showing which ones worked well together.

For the life of me, I cannot find this diagram (even though I am certain I had it printed out before). I've trawled google for the past couple of days but cannot find it. I'm starting to think that I might be going mad and just imagined the whole thing!

Help appreciated! =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know of this one from boardgamegeek which was tallied up from a [community vote](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/561975/vote-on-how-to-combine-expansions):

[image]

Comment: This is it! I just found as well... it is embedded in the Arkham Horros Stats google doc here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AliZyklaTCWzcGFQTWdvZW5jc1JwcHEzUEVZV1htUVE&hl=en_US#gid=34

Comment: Does Curse of the Dark Pharoah refer to the original version, revised version, or both versions?

Comment: @Thunderforge the boardgamegeek poll that resulted in this graph started before the revised edition was published, so I assume it refers to the original edition. However I couldn't tell you if the revised changes this, or is approximately the same, since I've never played the revised edition.